# Does Hosted Payment Page accept hosted_login_token?

Tags: recurly

Currently, I want to use Hosted Payment Page of Recurly for charging user. I wanna know if we can let user select their account billing information (credit card) in that page. Does Hosted Payment Page accept `hosted_login_token`? or is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosted pages are really just designed for interactions that require billing information. Since you already have that, you can use the regular Recurly API (subscription create  call) to add a new subscription to their account. Just reference the existing account_code, and Recurly will use that stored billing information.